# Get the name of celery worker from inside a celery task?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I'd like a celery task to be able to get the name of the worker executing it, for logging purposes.  I need to handle this from within the task, rather than querying the broker directly.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm using celery with RabbitMQ, if that matters.

Comment: Please set my solution to resolved if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `celeryd_after_setup` signal to capture the worker name like this:

```
from celery.signals import celeryd_after_setup

@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def capture_worker_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    os.environ["WORKER_NAME"] = '{0}'.format(sender)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, however I would put the name inside the celery config, and not in an environment variable

Comment: If you're using the `celery_worker` fixture to test, use the `worker_init` signal instead as `celeryd_after_setup` is not called in test.

Answer (score 7):

You need to utilize billiard which holds the workers:

```
from celery import task
from billiard import current_process

@task
def getName():
    p = current_process()
    return p.index
```

Then make a global dictionary that maps ids->names on process creation.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for.  When you start a celery worker, you can give it a name (-n flag).  I'm wondering if there is a way to get that name from within the task.

Comment: not quite as straight forward but why not make a global dict of ids->names?

Comment: billiard is definitely the key, but this solution does not get the name, as requested. I added a small update in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I also needed the worker name for reporting purposes so I tried @cacois solution but it doesn't seem to work with eventlet (current_process() doesn't have an initargs attribute). So I'll leave my solution here for future references:

```
from celery import task

@task(bind=True)
def getName(self):
    return self.request.hostname
```

The name of the attribute sounds weird to me, but that contains the name specified with the "-n" option when launching the worker. self works like you would expect from a class method, you don't need to specify it when calling the function (eg: getName.delay()).

Comment: You don't need to do this every time you run a task. Way easier to capture the worker name on connect. See my answer bellow.

Comment: Hostname is the name of the server, not the name of the worker.

Answer (score 3):

You were originally looking for the name you put in with the -n flag, right? It's in the initargs array. Here's a modified version of the answer that gets you that:

```
from celery import task
from billiard import current_process

@task
def getName():
    p = current_process()
    return p.initargs[1].split('@')[1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to no longer work with recent celery versions. `current_process()` now returns a `ForkProcess` object, which has no `initargs`.